# Installing mod_ext_filter on Apache 2.4.7 running on Centos 6

Tags: apache, centos

My hosting provider's Centos machine doesn't have Apache's 2.4.7's mod_ext_filter installed. I have been waiting a few days for them to install it, but I'm not confident that it's going to happen any time soon. So... I'd like to try to install the mod myself.

I have SSH access to the box, am root, and can do sudo/yum, etc. as needed. I tried a simple yum install mod_ext_filter in the hopes that it would work, but since mod_ext_filter is not a package, it "does nothing."

So, what's the easiest way for me to install the mod_ext_filter(.so) so that I can use the filter from Apache?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my hosting provider, Liquid Web, needed to recompile Apache from source, and needed to include the mod_ext_filter.c file in the compilation. Once they did this, I was able to implement the filter pretty easily.